# Combine data set from Two tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle12c

I have the below sample data in two table :

Table1

```
Item Loc Hierarchy Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4
I1   L1  Item      null null null D1
I2   L2  Item      null null null D2
I2   L3  Item      null null null D3
```

Table2

```
Item Loc Hierarchy Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4
     L1  ' '       A1   B1   C1   null
     L4  ' '       A4   B4   C4   null
```

Basically -

- Hierarchy column can have either 'Item' or ' ' values.
- Multiple combinations of Item@Loc can exist. But will have an Item entry only if Hierarchy is Item; Item column will be blank for ' ' hierarchy value.
- Loc can following possible scenarios-

One row with Val1, Val2, Val3 as null in Table1
and another row with Val1, Val2, Val3 with values and Val4 as null in Table2.

Only one row with Val1,2,3 values and Val4 as null in Table1; no row in Table2.

Only one row with Val4 value and Val1,2,3 as null in Table2; no row with Val1,2,3 values in Table1.

Expected Result-

```
Item Loc Hierarchy Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4
I1   L1  Item      A1    B1   C1   D1
I2   L2  Item      null null null D2
I2   L3  Item      null null null D3
     L4  ' '       A4   B4   C4   null
```

How can I combine the data and achieve the desired result? By Full outer Join? 
Is there any other alternative methods which are performance efficient OR a way of boosting the full outer join query. 
As this is a subset of a bigger query therefore once I achieve this result I have to use this data set to update another table which has some 100M records(  hence looking for performance efficient blocks).

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Just a side question: May we ask why you have single spaces as certain values instead of just using `NULL` or empty string?

Comment: I cannot maintain null in these. Its is the requirement to either use the Hierarchy or a space if no hierarchy defined.

Answer (score 1):

Use a union query:

```
SELECT
    MAX(Item) AS Item,
    Loc,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Hierarchy <> ' ' THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN MAX(CASE WHEN Hierarchy = ' ' THEN NULL ELSE Hierarchy END)
         ELSE MAX(Hierarchy) END AS Hierarchy,
    MAX(Val1) AS Val1,
    MAX(Val2) AS Val2,
    MAX(Val3) AS Val3,
    MAX(Val4) AS Val4
FROM
(
    SELECT Item, Loc, Hierarchy, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4 FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Item, Loc, Hierarchy, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4 FROM Table2
) t
GROUP BY
    Loc
ORDER BY
    Loc;
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this be faster than Full Outer Join ? I am using Full outer join and getting the result, but want to know if there is an alternative way too.

Comment: Well I am biased from your earlier question, which was basically just an aggregation brain teaser.  My thinking here was to just use the union to arrive at the same intermediate table from the earlier question.  You could try to use full outer join, but that seems scarier to me than my answer.

Comment: Yes I get that. I am scared too. Please let me know if you get any other alternative answers.Thanks for your help!

Comment: Um...I have given you an alternative to outer join already.  Not sure what you are trying to do here...

Comment: Yes and thank you for that , I will look into my updated requirements and post a different question if and as required.